# URL to access cluster environment for ElasticSearch2.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.4

We have an ElasticSearch2.4.3 cluster environment of two nodes. I want to ask what URL should I provide to access the environment so that it works in High Availability?

We have two master Node1 and Node2. The host name for Node1 is node1.elastic.com and Node2 is node2.elastic.com. Both the nodes are master according to formula (n/2 +1).

We have enabled cluster setting by modifying the elastic.yml file by adding 
**discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts** for the two nodes.

From our java application, we are connecting to node1.elastic.com. It works fine till both the nodes are up. Data is getting populated in both the ES servers and everything is good. But as soon as Node1 goes down entire elastic search cluster gets disconnected. And it automatically doesn't switch to Node2 for processing requests.

I feel like the URL which I am giving is not right, and it has to be something else to provide an automatic switch.

**Logs from Node1**
`[2020-02-10 12:15:45,639][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] initialized
[2020-02-10 12:15:45,639][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] starting ...
[2020-02-10 12:15:45,769][WARN ][common.network           ] [Wildpride] _non_loopback_ is deprecated as it picks an arbitrary interface. specify explicit scope(s), interface(s), address(es), or hostname(s) instead
[2020-02-10 12:15:45,783][WARN ][common.network           ] [Wildpride] _non_loopback_ is deprecated as it picks an arbitrary interface. specify explicit scope(s), interface(s), address(es), or hostname(s) instead
[2020-02-10 12:15:45,784][INFO ][transport                ] [Wildpride] publish_address {000.00.00.204:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::9af2:b3ff:fee9:90ca]:9300}, {000.00.00.204:9300}
[2020-02-10 12:15:45,788][INFO ][discovery                ] [Wildpride] XXXX/Hg_5eGZIS0e249KUTQqPPg
[2020-02-10 12:16:15,790][WARN ][discovery                ] [Wildpride] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
[2020-02-10 12:16:15,799][WARN ][common.network           ] [Wildpride] _non_loopback_ is deprecated as it picks an arbitrary interface. specify explicit scope(s), interface(s), address(es), or hostname(s) instead
[2020-02-10 12:16:15,802][WARN ][common.network           ] [Wildpride] _non_loopback_ is deprecated as it picks an arbitrary interface. specify explicit scope(s), interface(s), address(es), or hostname(s) instead
[2020-02-10 12:16:15,803][INFO ][http                     ] [Wildpride] publish_address {000.00.00.204:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::9af2:b3ff:fee9:90ca]:9200}, {000.00.00.204:9200}
[2020-02-10 12:16:15,803][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] started
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,552][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] stopping ...
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,619][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [Wildpride] [17] failed send ping to {#zen_unicast_1#}{000.00.00.206}{000.00.00.206:9300}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: can't add nodes to a stopped transport
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:916)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:906)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:267)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:395)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,620][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [Wildpride] failed to send ping to [{Wildpride}{Hg_5eGZIS0e249KUTQqPPg}{000.00.00.204}{000.00.00.204:9300}]
SendRequestTransportException[[Wildpride][000.00.00.204:9300][internal:discovery/zen/unicast]]; nested: TransportException[TransportService is closed stopped can't send request];
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:340)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.sendPingRequestToNode(UnicastZenPing.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.sendPings(UnicastZenPing.java:426)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$2.doRun(UnicastZenPing.java:249)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: TransportException[TransportService is closed stopped can't send request]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:320)
    ... 7 more
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,623][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] stopped
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,623][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] closing ...
[2020-02-10 12:16:35,642][INFO ][node                     ] [Wildpride] closed`

Comment: Could you post the logs of Node1?

Comment: Sorry, how can attach log file here?

Comment: edit you question, paste the logs. Then select it and click the <code> button

Comment: Added latest logs from Node1

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: There is no automatic switch in elasticsearch and you'll need some kind of loadbalancer in front of the elasticsearch cluster.**

For an HA setup, you need at least 3 master eligible nodes. In front of the cluster there have to be a loadbalancer (also HA) to distribute the requests across the cluster. Or the client needs to be somehow aware of cluster and in a failure scenario failover to any node left.

If you go with 2 master nodes, the cluster can get into the "split brain" state. If your network gets somehow fragmented and the nodes become invisible to each other, both of them will think it is the last one working and keep serving the read/write requests independently. In that way they drift away from each other and it will become nearly impossible to fix it - at least, when the fragmentation is gone, there is a lot of trouble to fix. With 3 nodes, in a fragmentation scenario the clusternwill only continue to serve requests if there are at least 2 nodes visible to each other.